# #1064 Error when creating a user table

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax-error

Hopefully my last question tonight. I searched the suggested answers StackOverflow gives, but can't find one to fix mine. Here's my code:

```
 CREATE TABLE `user_accounts` (
   `id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
   `email` text ,
   `password` char(32) DEFAULT NULL ,
   `active` tinyint DEFAULT '0' ,
   `groups` text ,
   `activation_key` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL ,
   `extras` text ,
   `PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
)   DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Here's my error:

```
    #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'id`), ) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8' at line 9
```

Line 9 is `PRIMARY KEY` (`id`)

Am I not defining something correctly?

Comment: Looks like you have been making a few question...still on "1 point" reputation...are you actually accepting any answers?

Comment: It wouldn't let me on my last question, I'll try again though in just a second

Comment: @Leo He's only made two questions and both were attempts to misuse Stack Overflow as an on-line syntax check service.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario hhahahaa...you cracked me up with..."online syntax check service"...I suggest this to Coding Horror's New Programming Jargon lol

Comment: I'm a she, not a he - first. Second, if this isn't to assist people learning coding why are you here? Please let me know if this forum isn't for asking genuine questions re: coding. I'll be happy to no longer utilize StackOverflow for such things.

Comment: The reason that many people don't like like the question is because it is simple typographical error. Granted some error messages are obtuse, but this one is not. There is nothing wrong with an occasional bad comma, missing semicolon, or typo. Those types of problems can be best addressed by understanding the nature of the error messages already given.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have  an extra comma at the end and extra backtick before PRIMARY KEY

```
CREATE TABLE `user_accounts` (
   `id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
   `email` text ,
   `password` char(32) DEFAULT NULL ,
   `active` tinyint DEFAULT '0' ,
   `groups` text ,
   `activation_key` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL ,
   `extras` text ,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)   DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

[**See fiddle demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7876e)

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE `user_accounts` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `email` text,
  `password` char(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `active` tinyint(4) DEFAULT '0',
  `groups` text,
  `activation_key` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `extras` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```